# Svelte switch/case vs. if logic blocks

Tags: javascript, typescript, logic, svelte

I was wondering whether there are any best practises on when to use a `switch`/`case` assignment vs. using `if` / `else if` logic blocks in svelte?

E.g. if I have an enum

```
export enum Status {
  riding = "RIDING",
  arrived = "ARRIVED",
  failed = "FAILED",
}
```

Is it better to use a switch case in the `script` tag

```
<script>
  let statusText = ""

  $: switch (status) {
    case Status.riding:
      statusText = "Riding"
      break
    case Status.arrived:
      statusText = "Arrived"
      break
    case Status.failed:
      statusText = "Failed"
      break
  }
</script>

<span class="status-text">
  {statusText}
</span>
```

…or to use `if` / `else if` logic blocks:

```
<span class="status-text">
  {#if status === Status.riding}
    "Riding"
  {:else if status === Status.arrived}
    "Arrived"
  {:else if status === Status.failed}
    "Failed"
  {/if}
</span>
```

Any recommendation on what to use? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a dictionary:

```js
$: statusText = {
  [Status.riding]: "Riding",
  [Status.arrived]: "Arrived",
  [Status.failed]: "Failed",
}[status];
```

Though it really does not matter (both markup and reactive expressions update just once when the dependencies have changed), and as soon as you need more than a string for content, you will have to use `{#if}`/`{:else if}` anyway.

Comment: Ah great thanks, I didn't think of a map.